# Finding the distance between two objects

Tags: c++, math, distance

For my game, I need to find the distance between two objects at certain times. My question is simply can the findDistance function be improved? I don't seem to have any issues, I'm only curious if it could have been done better. Also, if I were to do this in a 3D setting how would I go about calculating it since there is another axis?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

struct point{float x, y;};

float findDistance(point &x, point &y)
{
    float distance, tempx, tempy;
    tempx = (x.x - y.x);
    tempx = pow(tempx, 2.0f);
    tempy = (x.y - y.y);
    tempy = pow(tempy, 2.0f);
    distance = tempx + tempy;
    distance = sqrt(distance);
    return distance;
}

int main()
{
    point a, b;
    a.x = -2;
    a.y = -3;
    b.x = -4;
    b.y = 4;

    std::cout << "The distance between point x and y is: " << findDistance(a, b) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3d:

```
float findDistance(point &x, point &y)
{
    float distance, tempx, tempy, tempz;
    tempx = (x.x - y.x);
    tempx = tempx * tempx; //compiler _might_ be able to make this faster
    tempy = (x.y - y.y);
    tempy = tempy * tempy;
    tempz = (x.z - y.z);
    tempz = tempz * tempz;
    distance = tempx + tempy + tempz;
    distance = sqrt(distance);
    return distance;
}
```

Other than replacing `pos(x,2)` with `x*x`, this cannot be optimized and remain generic/accurate, but if you don't need generic, it can be faster:

```
bool distanceLessThan(point &x, point &y, float distance)
{
    float tempx, tempy, tempz, tempd;
    tempx = std::abs(x.x - y.x);
    tempy = std::abs(x.y - y.y);
    tempz = std::abs(x.z - y.z);
    if (tempx + tempy + tempz < distance) //for small distances, don't square
        return true;
    if (tempx + tempy + tempz > distance/2) //for large distances, don't square
        return false;
    tempx = tempx * tempx;
    tempy = tempy * tempy;
    tempz = tempz * tempz;
    tempd = distance * distance; 
    if (tempx + tempy + tempz < tempd)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `float distance` as input `float distance` as function variable, and micro optimization which causes to spaghetti coding.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: I agree it's ugly, and confusing.  [Ideone](http://ideone.com/NtMut) and MSVC10 say my comparison is _significantly_ faster though (Can't compare how much, it keeps timing equal to or faster than my "empty" loop).  Codepad appears to be broke ATM.

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach is fine and for new coordination just add it like others:

```
struct point{float x, y,z;};

float findDistance(point &x, point &y)
{
    float distance, tempx, tempy;

    tempx = (x.x - y.x);
    tempx = pow(tempx, 2.0f);
    tempy = (x.y - y.y);
    tempy = pow(tempy, 2.0f);
    tempz = (x.z - y.z);
    tempz = pow(tempz, 2.0f);
    distance = tempx + tempy + tmpz;
    distance = sqrt(distance);
    return distance;
}
```

In fact for n dimensions, you have the same formula for calculating distance, but you should add new dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

For 3D, just add a `tempz` to the distance:

```
tempz = (x.z - y.z);
tempz = pow(tempz, 2.0f);
distance = tempx + tempy + tempz;
```

By the way, "if it ain't broke, don't fix it."  No need to worry about changing what already works.

Answer (score 1):

I feel in general **pow( foo , 2 )** will be slower than **foo * foo**

Also ask yourself if in your calculations you need the distance or square_of_distance is sufficient.

For example to find which distance is greater you can simply compare square_of_distances instead of the the actual distance itself thereby saving a call to **sqrt**

Answer (score 0):

Pow() is for general floating point exponents, and is inefficient for computing squares. Use the obvious multiplication instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the z, but you can't really do much better than this. You can replace the pow(x, 2) with x * x, but that's about it.  If you don't need to know the distance, just whether two objects have collided then there are some optimizations, but otherwise:

```
float findDistance(point &x, point &y)
{
  float distance, tempx, tempy, tempz;
  tempx = x.x - y.x;
  tempy = x.y - y.y;
  tempz = x.z - y.z;
  distance = sqrt(tempx*tempx + tempy*tempy + tempz*tempz);
  return distance;
}
```

Is about the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

You *might* get better performance if you pass by value:

```
float findDistance(point a, point b)
{
    a.x -= b.x;
    a.x *= a.x; 
    a.y -= b.y;
    a.y *= a.y
    return sqrt(a.x * a.y);
}
```

Mooing Duck's answer contains everything else you should know.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the `pow` function:

```
distance = tempx*tempx + tempy*tempy;
```

and if you need the distance for collision detection, then you might consider using a square of the distances so that you don't need to call `sqrt()`.

But be aware of "premature optimization" and the 80-20 rule (80% of runtime is spent in 20% of the code), so maybe first run some performance tests and only if you see that you spend lots of time in the `findDistance` function, start to optimize it.